# Set focus on specific button when ContextDialog closed

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm sure this is a noob question, but can't figure out what's probably obvious.

In our app, a ContentDialog opens from a button press. When the ContentDialog closes, we'd like the focus to **return to the Page button that invoked it**. Now it goes to the first control on the Page (a TextBox). This is jarring, especially when using Narrator.

A Dialog_OnClosing event is already plumbed, but I can't figure out what to put here to put the focus on the button.

To clarify: answers so far will not work as stated, because the closing event is in the dialog. How do I set focus on a button in the invoking Page, NOT a button on the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

`buttonID.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);` should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

It inherits the `Focus` method and you can use it like this:

```
someButton.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

More about `Focus` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_Focus_Windows_UI_Xaml_FocusState_).